# What quantity is the operating point?

Tags: transistors

I have a problem with a question about a MOS transistor in common source setting.

Using the provided formulas I have calculated several quantities: \$V_G\$, \$V_{GS}\$, \$I_D\$, \$V_D\$ and \$V_S\$.

I'm supposed to calculate an operation point (the operation point?), but no definition was provided, and my google skills proved insufficient. It's probably something really obvious.

Which of the quantities (or maybe some other?) should I provide as a answer?.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, new user! We would love to help you, but I suppose it isn't clear what you're asking. Have you been given a circuit to analyse? Can you share the calculations you've already done?

Comment: When my teacher asks me for the operation point (or polarization point in my country) he is actually asking for what you just found, \$V_G\$, \$V_S\$, \$V_D\$  and \$I_D\$.

Comment: @Ricardo I think that maybe we are the ones that doesn't understand the question but actually it is pretty clear, is the MOSFET operating point under certain conditions, that is all.

Comment: I guess you're right! Now that you got a couple of answers, we'll be able to learn something new. I made that comment because I didn't understand why you were getting so many down votes without any comments explaining why.

Comment: I had an EE teacher whose definition of operating point was to draw an IV curve for the transistor in question.  So apparently "operation point" is not well defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operating point is nothing more than the values that you already found (mainly \$I_D\$, \$V_{GS}\$ and \$V_{DS}\$).

The small signal AC properties (like trans-conductance) of the transistor depend on its DC operating point.

The reason is that the curves that model its behavior are not straight lines, but for small signal AC analysis you can consider them as such, and the best approximation is a the line tangent to the curve at the operating point.  Considering straight lines allows you to use powerful mathematical tools for analysis and design.

Since the transistors have large signal non-linear mathematical models that are non-linear, when you use the formulas for AC analysis and plug in the operating point values, most (if not all) of these formulas came from taking the derivative of the large signal non-linear models to calculate the tangent line.

So you basically control the AC parameters of the transistor by setting its operating point, hence its relevance.

Additionally, in case you are dealing with large AC signals (where the linear models are inadequate), knowing the operating point helps in maximizing the swing/ranges of your signals.

Answer (score 2):

According to the book *Microelectronic Circuits* by *Sedra* & *Smith* (\$5^{th}\$ Edition, Page 154) for a diode "*The load line intersects the diode curve at point \$Q\$, which represents the **operating point** of the circuit. Its coordinates give the values of \$I_D\$ and \$V_D\$*" according to Figure 3.11.

[image: Diode Operating Point]

In the case of a MOS transistor the operating point \$Q\$ will be given by the load line intersecting the MOS line for the \$V_{GS}\$ that the transistor is under. This coordinates are given by \$I_D\$ and \$V_{DS}\$.